# google colablatory にファイルをアップロードすると1回目のみエラーが出ます

Tags: python, python3, google-colaboratory

```
img_file_path = files.upload()
```

google colablatory でこのコードを実行すると１回目にこのエラーが出力されます。

```
MessageError: TypeError: Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined
```

エラーメッセージをなくす方法をご教授お願い致します。

Comment: 「1回目のみ」と書かれているということは、2回目以降は予想通り動作するということでしょうか？

Comment: はい。２回目以降はファイルをアップロードできるようになってます。